# How can I change the caption font and size for figures and tables

Tags: captions, fontsize

I want to specify the figure caption font size in order to follow a stupid standard at my university. I need the font to be Arial (I am using Helvetica because Arial is not available for LaTeX) 11pt. I have found:

```
\usepackage[font=md,labelfont=bf]{caption}
```

I have defined Heveltica as the default font for the whole document, so this constrain is hold. However, I cannot specify the font size. Is there another way to solve this issue?

Comment: The fontsize for the document or for the captions?

Comment: 12pt. I have read that when the font size is 12pt, the font=small is  10.95pt, so I guess that solves my issue. Just waiting the one who is going to check that does not notice it.

Comment: If you would do this in Germany, there would be definitely one at the office, taking a ruler and measure the height of your letters ;-)

Comment: The real size depends on the class however, for example the class options `12pt` for `book.cls` will take the values from `book12.clo`

Comment: I'm from Ecuador, so here they won't use a ruler, but they would probably like to see some place where you have written the number 11.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You can say that again :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `\DeclareCaptionFont` and `\fontsize{<size>}{<baselineskip>}\selectfont` (`\mdseries` in the example below applies `\selectfont`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}

\DeclareCaptionFont{xipt}{\fontsize{11}{13}\mdseries}
\usepackage[font=xipt,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}

Regular text for comparison
\begin{table}
\caption{A test caption for a table}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
\caption{A test caption for a figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: What if I want the global font to be 12pt? I have notice that the solution you have provided solved my issue, but it emans that if I have set 12pt at the documentclass that is going to be the global font?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf I updated my answer with a global `12pt`. No matter what the global font you select, `\captionsetup` will override this and give you the desired formatting for the captions.

Comment: Why do I have to use `scaled=0.9` for the package helvet?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf just to have the Helvetic family fonts match nicely with other families. I don't know exactly what fonts packages are you using, so it might be the case that you wouldn't need to scale the font.

Comment: I guess that in my case it is not needed. The fonts that I am using are helvet instead of Arial and the other font is Times New Roman (`\fontfamily{ptm}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{16}{10}\selectfont`), but the last one is just for titles, subtitles (section and subsections).