# Caption package, how to set font point size with other customizations in captionsetup (question updated, more specific now)

Tags: captions, fontsize, overleaf

Edit: question updated to be more specific

I am creating a chapter report template in LaTeX that will be used by others, mostly in Overleaf. There are requirements for fonts, indentations, etc. that are in a Word template that I am coding into a LaTeX template. I am using Report document class with pdfLaTeX compiler in Overleaf.

I am setting up the figure captions as shown below using the [caption package](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption?lang=en) as recommended by @Zarko in the comments. The only thing that I can't seem to figure out is how to set the font size to a specific size.

I have tried `font=18pt`, `font={18pt}`, `font=\fontsize{18pt}{18pt}` etc. (and also `labelfont=` and `textfont=`) with no effect and an error message saying `Package caption Error: 18pt undefined in families caption@font`. What is the right format to explicitly define a font size in the *caption* package?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% set page dimensions
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry}

% set paragraph dimensions
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}

% set Calibri-like font
\usepackage[sfdefault]{carlito}

% format headers
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}%
    {\normalfont\fontsize{18pt}{0pt}\bfseries}%
    {\thechapter}{0.5in}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{22pt}{18pt}

% format figure captions
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup{format=plain, labelsep=period, singlelinecheck=false,%
    labelfont=bf, margin={0.2in}, hangindent=0.7in, skip=12pt}
    % NEED TO ADD FONT SIZE 18pt IN HERE

%-------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
This is introduction paragraph.

\section{Section}
Some details, see Figure \ref{fig:exA}.

\begin{figure}[b!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption[Short description.]{\lipsum[1]} 
\label{fig:exA}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For caption formatting I suggest to use package `caption`, Al it features are thoroughly described and illustrated in its documentation, which is part of any LaTeX installation.

Comment: @Zarko wow, that package is great, thank you, I made a lot of progress with it. I now have a single, focused question; OP updated

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341435/47927 (especially the alternative solution).

Comment: @JasperHabicht thank you, that would work. Is there a way to embed it fully in the `\captionsetup{}`, without the added step of `\DeclareCaptionFont`?

Comment: You can define your own font size with `\DeclareCaptionFont{eighteenpt}{\fontsize{18pt}{20pt}\selectfont #1}` and then refer to it via `\captionsetup{font=eighteenpt}`. Of course, you just add `font=eighteenpt` to the other stuff in `\captionsetup`.

Comment: I just discovered that the question to the above linked answer already is a duplicate. So, I guess, your question will be marked as duplicate as well. I think, `\DeclareCaptionFont{eighteenpt}{\fontsize{18pt}{20pt}\selectfont}` should also work as was proposed in the answer to the [first question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/257978/47927) on this topic.